# Can you run older Operating Systems on "Windows 10" motherboards?

Tags: operating-systems

I would like to know if there are any issues that may/will arise if I attempt to install Windows 7 on motherboards that specifically say their support is only for Windows 10. The reason why I'm asking is i'm looking to try to multi boot Windows 7, Windows 10 and even a Linux distro. I want to harness the full power of my hardware to run some programs in older OS and newer OS and hence, Virtual machines isn't my taste.

What does "Supported OS" really mean in a motherboard specification? [Take for example this motherboard](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MPG-Z590-GAMING-CARBON-WIFI/Specification)

First thing that comes to mind is hardware issues, but drivers are also usually backwards compatible as well for older operating systems. As there is little info about potential issues arising from running older OS on modern motherboards, I would like to know and expound on it more.

Comment: There will be No windows 7 drivers for that motherboard you posted

Comment: It might be that you end up with generic drivers that do not fully support the motherboard, or have motherboard devices that do not work at all. It may be that a new graphics card does not provide Windows 7 drivers, leaving you stranded on either ancient drivers, or on "basic" drivers that can just about push a 2D display, but not play any games. That would be the most obvious level of incompatibility you'll find.

Comment: If you want anything older than Window 7 like Vista your probably going to have to visualizer it as it is likely you will experience a large number of problems.

Answer (score 3):

**There is a chance that some specific thing might not have a windows 7 driver and might have to live without it.**

If you only care about Windows 7 then there should only be minor issues.  However, as time goes on there WILL be more and more compatibility issues until its not possible.

For example Windows 10 is the only way to get DirectX 12.

This might limit you in some games, or cause them to run slower but it should work.

Also some of your drivers you might have to run in compatibility mode which would be slower than with full support.

I recently experience someones Vista computer and accessing the web was a complete nightmare.  No modern web browsers support it, and the old version of the browser have major issues rendering web pages correctly.  Anything older is going have even greater issues.  So the choice was either Windows 10 or linux.

---

Linux

Linux is NOT necessarily an older OS.  Linux kernel version 5.x most likely have enough support to have a function computer.  However, some of your hardware might not work if you can't get drivers for.

Now if you use a kernel 2.6.# all bets are off.  Obviously 3.# are significantly better, and 4.# are significantly better than that.

Modern 5.# kernels have no issue with NVMe support or etc.  Linux does have some compatibility issues with high end graphics cards.  However, it usually means they run slower than in windows.  Every new release of GPU drivers makes things better.  If you have ALL modern drivers and the right other software you can play video games.

---

**You need to create c:\temp\offline or substitute it for an empty folder.**

Dism /Mount-Image /ImageFile:"F:\sources\boot.wim" /index:1 /MountDir:"C:\Temp\Offline"

Mount the wim file.

Dism /Add-Driver /Image:"C:\Temp\Offline" /Driver:"C:\SWSETUP\SP78930" /Recurse

Add drivers.

Dism /Unmount-Image /Mountdir:"C:\Temp\Offline" /commit

Then unmount the image and that's it.

The drivers can be added to the install.wim file in the same wa

Comment: But with my planned multi boot, i should get both of what Windows 7 and Windows 10 has to offer. Of course I'll only install apps that run best on DX12 on Windows 10, and I'll only install apps that can't run on Windows 10 on Windows 7. That's the basic premise of my multi boot. 

I'm pretty much trying to do what this guy did: https://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/239905-installing-windows-7-new-uefi-motherboard.html

Yes, Linux is not an old OS (sry if it looked that way in my OP). I currently have a dual boot of Win 10 and Linux on my laptop. I wanna challenge myselffurther

Comment: Just looking to further know if there are any more specific draw backs from trying to run Windows 7 on a modern motherboard that only supports Windows 10. Another that I can find is this: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1079955-installing-windows-7-on-a-new-motherboard/

Comment: You can use DISM to inject drivers right into the boot.wim and install.wim.  Another issue is USB 3.1/3.2 gen 1 and gen 2 didn't exist when windows 7 was around so those ports may or may not function depending on if you can find drivers.  Also I have no idea if NVMe is supported.

Comment: Most probably NVMe isnt supported because I haven't heard of it around the time Windows 7 came out. So i guess it all boils down to trying to get backwards-compatible drivers for Windows 7 or DISM. I will read up on how to do the DISM method to inject drivers. I dont use NVMe and still use old HDDs lol

Answer (score 1):

Running Windows 7 on such a machine may or may not work. Microsoft is working hard to eliminate Windows 7 as an installed machine, so it might not install.

All you can do is try.

I do this myself with a Virtual Machine and that works very well. I do have Windows 7 working this way